# How to get get username (or any other data) of the logged in user with React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

What would be the best and secure way to store a user logged in data (mainly username or uuid). So, I can use it in my other components? I have thought of several ways to do it.

1. Upon login/signup, store username in local storage, and remove it when authsession ends. (Very easy to implement, but most likely the least secure)
2. Pass email through the AuthLogin/AuthSignup methods, but I can't seem to figure out how to pass it through router. I also notice that this doesn't work if the browser gets refreshed, even if the user is still logged in.
3. Cookies (don't know how to use them with react yet).

My authLogin method:

```
export const authLogin = (email, password) => {
    return dispatch =>{
        dispatch(authStart());
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login/',{
            email: email,
            password: password,

        })
        .then(res => {
            const token = res.data.key;
            const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600 * 1000);
            localStorage.setItem('token',token);
            localStorage.setItem('expirationDate',expirationDate)
            localStorage.setItem('email', email)#method 1
            console.log("My token",localStorage.getItem('token'))
            dispatch(authSuccess(token,email));#method 2
            dispatch(checkAuthTimeout(3600));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(authFail(err))
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This is primarily opinion based, but I have always done it through the first method. Authenticate and then store the access token in the local storage or session storage.

Comment: I see. Thank you. The first method seemed "too easy" so I assumed it was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right idea. Authenticate the user as you are doing, store the token in localStorage, and save the user data in redux. Since refreshing causes the redux store to start fresh, and you still need your user data I would dispatch an action somewhere in your app, probably around the root of the app when it first mounts to get the logged in user data based on the token saved in localStorage.

Something like this:

```
class App extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        // User will come from the store. If we do not have a user,
        // but we have a token, then the user is logged in
        if (!this.props.user && sessionStorage.getItem('token')) {
          // a redux dispatch function to authenticate a JWT
          this.props.validateJWT();
        }
    }
}
```

As far as passing props through the router you would have to use a renderProp, which may be a little tricky. Can you please share your code for your router issue?